# Advanced PHP sessions

Tags: php, session

i'm looking for an advanced tutorial about PHP sessions. With a deep understanding of how they works, avoiding to get into the PHP source code (the Zend engine).

**EDIT**

I wanted to avoid the "PHP Source Code" (as my original question says), which means, avoid the C code from the Zend Engine (at that moment).

Comment: Umm... You want an *advanced* tutorial about *PHP* sessions, **without** getting into *PHP*? Have I got that straight?

Comment: Why would you want to learn PHP sessions without learning PHP?

Comment: Sorry, i was trying to not get into the actual Zend engine. I don't know too much about C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PHP sessions manual.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)  *WARNING: Has PHP Code.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want a decent tutorial on PHP sessions, I would [look over here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php).

Note that it's going to be very hard to gain a "deep understanding" of how they work *without getting into the PHP code*.

Answer (score 0):

There is the same mechanism with java/servlet if you can't bear php...

look for getSession in [HttpServletRequest](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)